# Using LINQ with EF Reverse POCO Generator?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Using EF Reverse POCO Generator, I've already created my database POCOs from existing databases, and can access using Dapper and DapperExtensions by writing SQL.  In some situations I may prefer to use Linq to Entities, but I don't see a DbContext anywhere.

Is there some tooling in EF6 that will allow me to generate the usable DbContexts without clobbering the models already in place?

Connection strings are in web.config.
POCOs are in Database/dbname/*.cs

I've tried modifying parts of the T4 from EFRPG to make it generate a DbContext class, to no avail.

Comment: EF Reverse POCO Generator should also have generated a context class.

Comment: @GertArnold That would have been nice, but perhaps my edits of the T4 broke it.  I'll try with a new project and default EFRPG tt.

Comment: Yup I had messed up the T4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A DbContext doesn't create or alter your POCOs, it just uses them. You should be able to simply create a class that inherits from DbContext, add your POCOs as DbSets, and access them.

Something like this should work:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext : base(/* your connection string name*/) {}

    DbSet<myPOCO> myPOCOs {get; set;}
    //etc...
}
```